# Losing session data after redirecting from a 3rd party API (payment gateway)

Tags: c#, api, google-chrome, redirect, session-state

I'm working on an e-commerce site which is built on top of `ASP.NET MVC`. We are using 3rd party payment gateway for online payment transactions. Basically, I'm redirecting the user to the payment gateway with a `successUrl` and a `failUrl`. If everything goes okay then the payment gateway redirects the user to my `successUrl`.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm losing all session data as soon as the user is redirected to my `successUrl`. So, I'm unable to track this user and I can't process the order further. More details:

1. I'm using `InProc` SessionState
2. I have defined `timeout` in SessionState but that doesn't help
3. I've also defined `Session.Timeout` in the `Session_Start` method of `Global.asax` file
4. Currently my application uses `http` and the payment gateway uses `https`
5. Payment gateway is built on top of `PHP`

**What I've tried:**

I've created a dummy API then sent a request to it from my e-commerce app and then redirected it to my e-commerce app. In this case I don't lose my session data. So, I'm not sure what is wrong here.

I know there is work around but I'm more interested to know why I'm losing the session data. What's really going on behind the scene? What can I do to solve this problem? If you can elaborate it would really help.

**Update**

> I've just tested my solution in Firefox (version 76.x) and my solution
> works!! But it doesn't work on chrome (version 75.x)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether it's your problem or not but this year we've struggled from the same thing in our payment gateway and we realized that problem occurs from [SameSite issue of Chrome](https://blog.heroku.com/chrome-changes-samesite-cookie#:%7E:text=These%20changes%20will%20dramatically%20impact,cookies%20to%20target%20their%20audience.&text=Starting%20February%204%2C%202020%2C%20Google,an%20IETF%20standard%20called%20SameSite%20.). Adding some parameters to web.config fixed the issue for us.

For .NET 4.7.2 and above use

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>  
  <sessionState cookieSameSite="None" /> 
 <system.web>
<configuration>
```

For older versions:

```
<system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=None" />
          <conditions>
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
          <preCondition name="No SameSite">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
            <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=None" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="\(iP.*; CPU .*OS 12" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14.*Safari" negate="true" /> 
          </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
      </outboundRules>
   </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: intellisense shows `cookieSameSite` is not allowed. Tried though but doesn't work.

Comment: Which .net version you are using?

Comment: which browser you are using? I've just tested in Firefox my code works without any changes but it doesn't work in chrome.

Comment: Hi! After trying the code for older version I get an error message from chrome says `This site can't provide a secure connection `

Comment: That could be about ssl sertification are you sure all that fine?

Comment: I'm using `http` not `https`. Should I make any changes to your code?

Comment: Please replace  <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=None" /> to  <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=None; Secure" /> and let me know about the result.

Comment: Samesite none means, you share your cookies with third party applications. It seems browser doesn't allow to do with none secure connection. It's more network related from now on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this code to Global.asax `Session_Start` event

```
if (Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null)
{
    Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
}
```

Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite) document for more details.

Comment: Hi! I'm using .NET 4.5. I got a error message that says, `System.Web.HttpCokkie does not contain a definition for SameSite`

Comment: Can you target to 4.7.2?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it after spending an entire day behind it and going through lots of articles at SO and elsewhere:

Step 1: Changed the Target Framework to 4.7.2 (it was 4.5.2 earlier)

Step 2: Added the below 2 lines to the system.web section in the web.config file:

```
    <sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>
```

That's all it took to get it going. Now it works both in Chrome and Firefox (yet to be tested on another browsers, but hopefully, it will work on other browsers too).

PS:

- I know I have made a compromise in overall security by setting cookieSameSite to "None", but will definitely take steps to address that next.
- I was so much drowned in the problem, and then in the resolution that I felt so happy after getting through that it made me to write my first ever answer at SO. So, please be gentle while commenting on the same if you do.

Thanks.